# How does RFID reader energize passive tag

Tags: rfid

I'm reading the [EPCGlobal Gen2 protocol](http://chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/https://www.gs1.org/sites/default/files/docs/epc/uhfc1g2_2_0_0_standard_20131101.pdf) and [RFID and Sensor Networks](https://books.google.com/books?id=SIJLavpUAJoC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=session&f=false), and was confused by the following description about the Use of Session: " Session S0 has a persistence time of zero, so in this case, the reader must continually energize the tags. This is achieved by the reader transmitting the CW between commands. When using session S0, the inventoried flag of any tag that loses power during this process will revert to A regardless of its previous value. "

Does it mean that the reader will only energizing tags while transmitting CW, and the tags will not be powered when the reader sends commands like Select/Query, etc?

Answer (score 1):

The tags will stay energized as long as they stay within the electromagnetic field of the antenna.

In other words, an do try to make it simply, the tags will be energized from the moment they have been detected by the RFID reader antenna and until they leave that detection range (even briefly).